# Shell script in Jenkins doesn't get info about POM_VERSION/POM_ARTIFACTID with Promotion Build plugin

Tags: shell, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to execute shell script with Promotion Build plugin to get info about maven properties (POM_VERSION, POM_ARTIFACTID).

Trouble is values for Jenkins environment variables are shown, but info about maven properties are shown empty. Projects where I am testing are MVN projects.

```
echo $POM_ARTIFACTID

echo $POM_VERSION

echo $PROMOTED_JOB_NAME
tests

echo $JOB_NAME
tests/promotion
```

These are the versions I am using:

- Jenkins 2.44
- Maven Project Plugin 2.14
- Promoted Builds Plugin 2.28.1

### Anyone knows some solution for this?

Edit: Adding Following Problem Statement

1. Execute builds of different jobs
2. In case of green ball, we want to execute a script. In this script, we do two actions:
3. Transferring artifact .WAR generated after correct build to another machine.
4. Launch deploy in this another machine.

Trouble is locating path where war is generated, The WAR file has this file name format: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/$PROMOTED_JOBNAME/target/$POM_A‌​RTIFACTID-$POM_VERS‌​ION.war so, I need info about pom_artifactID and pom_version to have path for .WAR and execute shell script.

Comment: Where have you defined POM_ARTIFACTID and  POM_VERSION ? Promoted Build Plugin do not expose these properties

Comment: Hi GauravJ, I have not defined these properties. I think that Maven Project Plugin let exposing these properties.
Where I should define these properties to shell script load this info?

Answer (score 0):

POM_ARTIFACTID, POM_VERSION are not defined by promoted build plugin. For list of properties exposed, refer [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin). More specifically "Available Environment Variables" section.

POM version and artifact id are available in post build when maven plugin has run. I don't think pom version are available at promote build action. See section [Promotion Action](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin)

From the problem statement, it looks like [build pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) or [multijob](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) plugin is better fit.

More specifically, in multijob plugin you can create different phases with build, deploy as different phase which run one after the other. From maven job, you also pass POM version and artifactid to other project using phase parameters in post build actions.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I continue with the same problem.

Comment: Could you please explain in your original question what you were trying to achieve ? It is possible to have different way of doing that.

Comment: I try to explain with more details (two comments):

1.- Execute builds of different jobs. 

2.- In case of green ball, we want to execute a script.

3.- In this script, we do two actions:

3.1.- Transferring artifact .WAR generated after correct build to another machine.

3.2.- Launch deploy in this another machine.

Comment: Trouble is locating path where is generated .WAR, has the same format:
 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<PROMOTED_JOB_NAME>/target/<POM_ARTIFACTID>-<POM_VERSION>.war

so, I need info about pom_artifactID and pom_version to have path for .WAR and execute shell script.

Hope you have understand my question.

Comment: Modified my answer